# Recycle Bin crashes explorer.exe

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, recycle-bin

I accidentally deleted a folder containing a couple hundred thousand files. It's (presumably) currently in my recycle bin. Attempting to open the recycle bin, however, is futile, as explorer.exe crashes after a few minutes of the green progress bar failing to reach the end. How can I restore my files?

Comment: You can use something like WinDirStat to confirm your recycle bin currently is using  the correct amount of storage.  Typically though Windows doesn't allow unlimited space in the bin.  So it's very possible your deletion was a permanent deletion

Comment: Are you looking for another app to do this like a software recommendation?

Comment: Maybe write C# code to restore all files from the recycle bin of the matching SID # directory, and then run that from PowerShell. A bit too much for me but an idea maybe someone can speak too even if just the C# code getting that to run from PS should be simple enough to figure out.

Comment: is explorer crashing or only hanging?

Comment: Undo with Ctrl+Z to move that folders to their previous path. Or use CD and move commands in CMD.

Comment: @Biswapriyo That's what ended up working. Feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it'll work, but you could try to use another file manager.

I use [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) instead of Windows Explorer, and it works better in just about every regard.